# How to deduplicate and centralize pictures from multiple cameras?

Tags: picasa, date, duplicates

I have several cameras, some retired and/or broken, some working, some not. Their pictures are scattered across several computers, possibly with duplicates, and the original SD cards. The naming format is not consistent, dates possibly broken, and maybe not all the pictures are on the computers.

So what I need is a tool/way to:

- Collect images (can do manually)
- Deduplicate them based on image data or hash
- Store all of them in day-based or month-based folders so I can back them up on a external HDD

Note to duplication: The options in the dupe tag don't have any way of moving pictures based on date, preferably extracted from the EXIF data.
And Picasa is more of a Google-syncer and centralized photo manager that operates on photos from many sources, and I couldn't find the option for actually reorganizing the photos on disk.

Comment: Have you looked at the duplicate tag on this site(http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/duplicates) or searched for existing questions on this topic? What did you find? What didn't that answer?

Comment: This was marked as a duplicate because 5 out of 5 people who reviewed it found it close enough to the duplicate question for its answers to answer this question.  You may be able to get it re-opened if you edit the question so it's just concentrating on the part the other "duplicate" doesn't already cover.  Since you are sort of asking multiple things at once, there's probably scope to do so.

Answer (score 0):

A way you can deduplicate your images is to run each file through a MD5 coder. if the files are exactly the same then the MD5 code will be exactly the same. the best way would be is to load all of the pictures into the same location. then use a scripting language to run through each file and generate the MD5 code and to compare MD5 codes.

You might find a solution on stackoverflow.com (another one of the stack exchange sites); this might be a better question to ask on stackoverflow.com